# How to load excel template and write to it in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, templates, phpexcel

How do I load an Excel Template with PHPExcel and write to its cells and also insert images to cells dynamically?

Comment: Answers to these questions are provided in the Documentation, together with examples on how to do them

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can read your excel template like this with PHPExcel:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("./forms/english/cash.xlsx");
```

and you can write to cells like this:

```
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                            ->setCellValue('A2', "No")
                            ->setCellValue('B2', "Name")
                            ->setCellValue('C2', "Email")
                            ->setCellValue('D2', "Phone")
                            ->setCellValue('E2', "Address");
```

Answer (score 8):

see the example, 30template.php in github site

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/30template.php

load template :

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("templates/30template.xls");
```

see in the example write via

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue()
```

to add image use PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing :

```
// Add an image to the worksheet
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('My Image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('The Image that I am inserting');
$objDrawing->setPath('./images/myImage.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B2');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Comment: how to write inside the template and how to add images

Comment: Image Resize: $objDrawing->setResizeProportional(true);
$objDrawing->setWidthAndHeight(230, 170);

Answer (score 1):

Now you don't need load templates. Try to use the PHP Excel templator:
https://github.com/alhimik1986/php-excel-templator